# DWT Condition with FieldPath

Tags: templating, dwt

With a DWT, how to test if an embedded schema field has a value in a condition?  The following code does not work and breaks on the TemplateBeginIf condition.  Is this possible with a DWT?

```
<OffersText>
    <Title>Some title</Title>
    <Body>
        Body text
    </Body>
    <Select>Offer A</Select>
</OffersText>

<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="OffersText" --> 
  <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="FieldPath + '.Select' = 'Offer A'" -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 LeftGutter LeftGutterT RightGutter RightGutterT">
      <p>SomeHTML Here...</p>
    </div>
  <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code inside the `<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat -->` has context... Just test your value as such.
Also, you need an "is equal to" operator, rather than an "equals" I think ;)

The following works for me...

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="OffersText" --> 
  <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Select == 'Offer A'" -->
    <div class="col-sm-3 LeftGutter LeftGutterT RightGutter RightGutterT">
      <p>SomeHTML Here...</p>
    </div>
  <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```